# Adding cloth displaces mesh geometry

Tags: modifiers

When I add a Cloth modifier to an FBX-imported mesh ("thread004"), the mesh suddenly jumps to a new location distant from its origin.   Is there a way to prevent this?   The "thread004" mesh was previously wound onto its parent ("spool002") and its therefore important to keep it exactly placed as spool002 will be a collision object.
Before adding Cloth:
[image: Before adding Cloth]

If I switch to edit mode, the cloth returns to surrounding the spool.  blend is tiny over 30MB so here's a: [public URL](http://optionpeer.com/jimtpersonal/Cloth_Problem.blend)

After adding Cloth

[image: After adding Cloth]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your timeline starts 885 and ends with 1500. The cloth sim starts at 1, which makes it jump.
Reset the beginning and end according to your timeline and then rewind once.
The rope will jump back where it started.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, Mr Holmes!  Dr Moriarty couldn't get away with anything around you !